# Problem displaying custom error message using a Login Control.

Tags: c#, asp.net, authentication

I have a `Asp:Login` control in my project, works well in terms of the setting the passing values and managing the event handlers.

However the problem is despite setting the `errorMessages` it's always showing a `*` instead of the custom message. This the markup of the `asp:login` control :

```
    <asp:Login ID="lgnApp" runat="server" DestinationPageUrl="~/Default.aspx" 
            LoginButtonText="Entrar"              
            RememberMeText="Recuerdáme"
            TitleText="" 
            UserNameLabelText="Usuario:" 
            onauthenticate="lgnApp_Authenticate" 
            onloggedin="lgnApp_LoggedIn" Width="296px" 
            DisplayRememberMe="False" 
            onloginerror="lgnApp_LoginError" 
            PasswordRequiredErrorMessage="Password it-s required">
        <LabelStyle CssClass="formatText" />
        <TitleTextStyle CssClass="formatText" />
    </asp:Login>
```

I don't know if I need to manage the display of this message manually?

Here's an image of the display message

[image: Note's that always show a * instead the custom message]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your page doesn't have a `ValidationSummary` control.

[According to MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.login.passwordrequirederrormessage.aspx), messages such as `PasswordRequiredErrorMessage` will only be displayed if there is a `ValidationSummary` control on the page.

The `ValidationGroup` property of the `ValidationSummary` control should be set to the ID of the Login control.

Comment: When informe the ValidationGroup, take care, the ValidationGroup is case-sensitivity!